# prime faces theme switcher: how to add themes to my project

Tags: primefaces

see my code

theme.xhtml

```
<h:form>
<h:panelGrid>
    <p:themeSwitcher style="width:165px" effect="fade" var="th" id="themePreview" >  
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Choose Theme" itemValue="" />  
        <f:selectItems value="#{themeBean.themesList}" var="theme" itemLabel="#{theme.name}" itemValue="#{theme}"/>  

        <p:column>  
            <p:graphicImage value="images/#{th.image}"/>  
        </p:column>    
        <p:column>  
            #{th.name}  
        </p:column>  
    </p:themeSwitcher>  
    </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

ThemeBean

```
themesList= new ArrayList<Theme>();     
    themesList.add(new Theme("afterdark","afterdark.png"));
    themesList.add(new Theme("aristo","aristo.png"));
    themesList.add(new Theme("eggplant","eggplant.png"));
    themesList.add(new Theme("humanity","humanity.png"));
    themesList.add(new Theme("sunny","sunny.png"));

}

public List<Theme> getThemesList() {
    return themesList;
}

public void setThemesList(List<Theme> themesList) {
    this.themesList = themesList;
}
```

Theme.java

```
private String name;
private String image;

public Theme(String name, String image)
{
    this.setImage(image);
    this.setName(name);
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

I followed the prime faces example.

I configured theme jars in build path xml also

but I am not getting even selection in the theme switcher(List Box)

can any one suggest me what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Primefaces Theme Switcher Example](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/examples/trunk/showcase/src/main/webapp/ui/themeswitcher.xhtml?r=7470)

They Show how can you code for this its very simple example  .

One More good tutorial here[Theme tutorial](http://courses.coreservlets.com/Course-Materials/pdf/jsf/primefaces/PrimeFaces-Themes.pdf)